# Add "Lion" tag to synonyms for OSX-10.7

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

People seem to be using the tag [lion](/questions/tagged/lion) to refer to OSX-10.7 a lot.  Since they are the same thing, they should be synonyms.  [osx-10.7](/questions/tagged/osx-10.7) should be the preferred usage, as lion is a vague term.

Every day I have been retagging 6-10 new Lion posts to OSX-10.7, as I think it's better to have a single tag rather than two that mean the same thing.

Comment: Let's add the `[rawr]` tag, too!

Answer (score 7):

The numbered versions for Mac OS X tags do not appear to be that popular:

- [macosx-10.5](/questions/tagged/macosx-10.5) = 80 questions
- [osx-10.6](/questions/tagged/osx-10.6) = 18 questions
- [osx-10.7](/questions/tagged/osx-10.7) = 43 questions

The corresponding cat names, however, are:

- [leopard](/questions/tagged/leopard) = 150 questions
- [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard) = 784 questions
- [lion](/questions/tagged/lion) = 5 questions, but it's been actively neutered by Mystere Man

I think we should stick with the cat names.

Regardless, some cleanup/consistency is needed here.  I propose either we stick with the cat names as-is or make those synonyms for [osx-leopard](/questions/tagged/osx-leopard), [osx-snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/osx-snow-leopard), [osx-lion](/questions/tagged/osx-lion).  Version numbers aren't what Apple or the public at large uses to refer to a version of OS X.

Comment: +1 for **`osx-lion`** and such. **`name-version`** is the usual convention, we shouldn't deviate from that just because we're identifying the versions by name instead of number.

Answer (score 2):

I've got no problem with setting up suitable synonyms, but given that Apple are referring to their own operating system as 'OS X Lion'  rather than '10.7' (http://www.apple.com/macosx/) I have to respectfully suggest that your current choice of preferred synonym is incorrect.

Comment: Speaking as a dyed-in-the-wool Apple user, I frankly don't think it matters what they want to call it in their marketing material. Here on SE we need a clear and unambiguous way to tag questions. The term "Lion" is much more likely to be used by someone else for something else than "OS X 10.7".

Comment: @josh, I guess the question is what will people visiting this site call it? Given that the tags can be used to find and classify similar posts, if you use tag names too different to what question-askers would use then you're breaking that, aren't you?

Comment: Visitor's usage is a concern, but this is one of the things synonyms address: if a decision is made by the regular users of the site to use a certain tag in favor of another, then all use by visitors of the second tag will be silently and painlessly converted to the first, including searches.

Comment: @Josh I understand your point but... I guess it just bemuses me and somewhat offends my sense of 'how things should be' that we would intentionally alias the correct name of an OS as a synonym of an incorrect name. As Daniel notes, the 'cat' names seem to be more popular and in the case of Lion, its the actual name of the actual product, so it makes sense to me to respect that. In any case, rather than go around in circles, I agree that whatever name is ultimately 'blessed' as the 'correct' one here it does make sense to get synonyms created one way or another.

Comment: Tag synonyms solve this problem quite well. Let people enter `[lion]` and let the system automagically correct that to `[osx-10.7]`. I agree with Josh. Version numbers are the most appropriate thing to use for tags here.

Answer (score 1):

Since [lion](/questions/tagged/lion) was far and away the most popular, I went with [Daniel's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99481/add-lion-tag-to-synonyms-for-osx-10-7/99487#99487) and merged / synonymized [osx-10.7](/questions/tagged/osx-10.7) with it. We can switch this around easily enough if necessary, but for now it seems the most straight-forward solution.

Comment: I still feel that lion is too vague of a term.  If anything, it should be osx-lion.  It's not entirely clear to someone who is not familiar with Macos that lion is reserved for that.

Comment: It is osx-lion - with lion as a synonym (follow the link).